# Handling padding and null overlap in raster tiles with PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm working with raster tiles in PostGIS and have encountered a complex issue related to padding and null data. I would like to find the best approach to manage this situation.

**Background:**
I've loaded raster data into a PostGIS table using `raster2pgsql`. Since my tiles need to be of the same size for the `enforce_raster_width` constraint, I've included padding, but this has introduced a problem where there is overlap between adjacent tiles. Some of this overlap includes null or no-data values. I understand it is a good idea in general to keep the tiles the same size.. I could remove the constraint.. but it feels weird to remove constraints that I assume are there for good reason.

**Problem:**
When I try to union or merge these raster tiles, the no-data values from the overlap are being included in the final image. This is resulting in no-data gaps in the final result instead of seamlessly merging the tiles where there is actual data.

Here's the SQL query I'm using:

```sql
WITH
raster AS (
    SELECT ST_SRID(rast) AS srid
    FROM naip LIMIT 1
),
joined AS (
    SELECT ST_Union(
        ST_Clip(mosaic.rast, roi.bounds)
    ) AS aoi_raster
    FROM naip AS mosaic, roi
    WHERE
        mosaic.filename LIKE '%201810%' AND
        ST_Intersects(mosaic.rast, roi.bounds)
)
SELECT lo_from_bytea(0, ST_AsPNG(aoi_raster, ARRAY[1, 2, 3])) FROM joined;
```

**Attempts:**
I've tried adjusting padding and even removed it altogether, which resulted in check constraint violations due to differing tile widths. I've also experimented with different `ST_Union` options but haven't found a solution that works.

**Question:**
How can I merge these raster tiles in a way that only includes the actual data, ignoring the null padding?

Comment: One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your question to remove the bullet list of questions.